# Why does this xpath query not work in Event Viewer in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, powershell, xpath, event-viewer

I wanted to be able to search the Event Viewer in using XPATH on Windows 10, but doesn't seem to accept the query.

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">/*[contains(text(), 'Admin')]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Comment: Because the XPath implementation for the Event Log service in Windows has some [serious limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/consuming-events#xpath-10-limitations) (iow: `contains()` is not available)

Comment: `get-winevent security | ? message -match admin`